# How to access some specific classes in a column using r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am having problems with accessing specific classes in a column. I have the dataframe as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  class = c("a","a","b","b","c","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))
```

In the column `time` I'm interested in detecting only `Breakfast` and `Dinner` for class `a`, `b` and `c` So from that dataframe i just want to view it in table and it will look like this:

```
            a    b    c
Breakfast   2    2    1
Dinner      2    3    2
```

so for each class `a`,`b`,`c` I want to draw two bars. For example class `a` one bar represent: The average of `Breakfast` compare to other classes: 2/(2+2+1) and one other bar represent `Dinner` compare to other classes : 2/(2+3+2) and set them to different colors. I want to same for class `b` and class `c`.

Any help for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `subset` and `table` after dropping the `levels` with `droplevels`

```
table(droplevels(subset(dat, time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner"))))
#           class
#time        a b c
#  Breakfast 2 2 1
# Dinner    2 3 2
```

If we need a `barplot`

```
barplot(prop.table(table(droplevels(subset(dat, time %in% 
            c("Breakfast", "Dinner")))), 1), beside = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
   filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
   droplevels %>%
   count(time, class) %>% 
   group_by(time) %>% 
   mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = class, y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
   geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
   geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Yes but if I want to draw the bar to represent the percentage for each class a,b,c what can I do? Can you help me?

Comment: I want just two difference bars next to each other for each class

Comment: If I want to draw it with ```ggplot``` and ```geo_bar``` can you propose solution?

Comment: Yep Thank you I voted it up and just a little bit question if I want to add percentage to each bar what should I add?

Comment: @Ben10 not clear about your question.  you. want to addd text?

Comment: Basically, yes I want to add text like percentage for each bar in those 3 classes we used ```geom_text``` and add what kind of arguments can you tell me ?

Comment: Yep Thank you so much I will adjust the color, position and size by myself